# 3D similarity search software

Tags: molecular-structure, software

What software / webservice can one use to find a compound that has similar 3D structure/dimension to another compound?

eg. say we are tying to find a 'better' version of atropine, so naturally we try to find compound with similar 3D structure to [Atropine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atropine) (antimuscarinic)

and [3d structure of atropine](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/174174#section=Top) (and all other drugs) is available

so what software can we run to search 3d shape look-alike of atropine among all available 3d structures ?

similar shape and size for starter?

[image: atropine-3d-structure]

Comment: This is pretty difficult to do. Most of the time, people go through crystal structure databases and look for molecule-looking fragments. But there's a reason that industry researchers spend entire careers doing this (and the related modelling).

Comment: It's not that there aren't software products that do this. The problem is having the database of accurate 3D molecular structures.

Comment: Probably the closest to your need would be [pharmit](http://pharmit.csb.pitt.edu) by David Koes, which allows you to search chemical libraries based on structural or chemical similarity to another small molecule, typically for protein binding